# in firefox entering data into a textbox which acts as a radio button needs a double click

Tags: javascript, html

In mozilla firefox entering data into a textbox which acts as a radio button needs a double click...how to make it possible through single click.Even after selecting the radio button and If i click the textbox once and try to enter only the radio button gets selected and the data is not entered.

Comment: If you want an answer, I think you should explain more, and possibly show your code :) Do you know http://jsfiddle.net/? With no context, impossible to find the cause of your problem!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sujitha123/xckvg6gr/        @Jean-PierreDelacre

Comment: PLS TRY THE JSfIDDLE IN FIREFOX...ONLY IN THAT I FACE THAT ISSUE

Answer (score 0):

For Firefox, the first click in to select the radio button, which gets the focus (honnestly don't know why it's different with other browsers).

I think your solution will be to use Javascript... See this [jdfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xckvg6gr/7/), I've update your code ;)

The idea is to have two inputs not linked in the HTML, but linked via the onclick (or onfocus) function, like:

```
<input type="radio" name="address-chosen" value="1" id="address-switch_1"  />
<input type="text" name="address-item_1" value="1" onclick="selectRadioButton('address-switch_1')"/>
```

My question is: what's your final objective? Because when you submit the form, you'll have to take into account that you have two separate inputs... or maybe update the value of the radio button with JS, too?

Comment: Actually Only on selecting the radio button the corresponding textbox wil get enabled.in That case on the first click i want to enter the data.